# How do I write a Mockito test case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Hi I was writing a test case for

```
    @Override

    public SnapDocument updateFlights(SnapDocument snapDocument, FlightListingResponse flightsResponse) {

        HashMap<String, FaresInfo> outboundFlights = new HashMap<>();

        HashMap<String, FaresInfo> inboundFlights = new HashMap<>();

        Objects.requireNonNull(flightsResponse.getOutboundFlights()).getFlights().forEach(faresInfo -> outboundFlights.put(faresInfo.getJourneySellKey(), faresInfo));

        Objects.requireNonNull(flightsResponse.getReturnFlights()).getFlights().forEach(faresInfo -> inboundFlights.put(faresInfo.getJourneySellKey(), faresInfo));

        snapDocument.setOutboundFlights(outboundFlights);

        snapDocument.setInboundFlights(inboundFlights);

        return snapDocument;

    }
```

This is the test case I have written

```
    public void updateFilghtsSuccess(){
            when(snapService.getSnapDocument(any())).thenReturn(snapDocument);
            when(snapService.updateFlights(snapDocument, flightListingResponse)).thenReturn(snapDocument);
            verify(snapService).updateFlights(snapDocument, flightListingResponse);
        }
```

The build is failing, How to write the test cases for this so that I can improve the coverage of my code?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Nothing here tests anything in that method at all--you're not verifying that any methods used by `updateFlights` have been called etc. Note, however, that if you're testing `updateFlights` you likely want to test the resulting `snapDocument` rather than the internal implementation of `updateFlights`, but how easy *that* is to test may dictate how `updateFlights` ends up being tested.

Answer (score 0):

`when`, `given` and `verify` should only be used when dealing with mocks.
As your code works with plain old java objects and no other external components are called, you do not need them.

Just construct the pojos to pass to the method and assert that the pojo that comes back out contains the correct values. You don't need mockito for that, as the test does not require mocks.

```java
@Test
void testUpdateFlights() {
    // Arrange
    SnapService snapService = new SnapServiceImpl();
    SnapDocument sd = new SnapDocument();
    FlightListingResponse response = new FlightListingResponse();
    response.setOutboundFlights(...);
    response.setReturnFlights(...);

    // Act
    SnapDocument result = snapService.updateFlights(sd, response);

    // Assert
    assertThat(result.getOutboundFlights()).contains(...);
}
```

You do not need them now, but when would you need a mock? If your code calls a component that is not under test and you don't want that the actual implementation of it is executed. Unit tests are to test 1 unit of work. All other external components should be mocked out.